# How to use "any of"

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural

Am I using *any of* correctly in these sentences?

> **Any of** its members **are** admitted.
>
> **Any of** its members **is** admitted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I initially guessed the correct choice would be

> Any of its members **are** admitted.

My reasoning went thus: 
We use "members" in the plural form, hence "any" are plural. Because, even if only one subject, or no subject at all, of these "members" will eventually be indeed admitted, "any of them" are allowed for admission at outset, hence, the sentence refers to a plural number of subjects.

But what if there's only one member?

I did some googling, and it turns out any of your options **is** admitted: here's a link to [a grammar blog post](http://ictyenglish.blogspot.ru/2005/11/grammar-tip-3-singular-or-plural-with.html). I quote:

> **Any of** can be followed by a verb in the singular or plural: "If **any of** your friends **want/wants** to come, they are welcome." (Plural is preferred in everyday language, singular is more formal)

Or, as the same issue it treated in [a grammar rule sheet](http://www.victoria.ac.nz/st_services/slss/studyhub/handouts/Singular-or-plural.pdf) at a New Zealand university site,

> When **any of** is followed by a countable plural noun, the verb can be in either singular or plural form, but a singular verb is more common in a formal style: "If **any of** your friends **is/are** interested, let me know."