# Singular or plural noun: "whether any of Dr Jones's acquaintances knows/know"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> An investigation is underway to discover whether any of Dr Jones's acquaintances **knows/know** where he is.

In my opinion, after 'any of' and a plural noun, we can use either a singular or plural verb, but I'm confused about the answer is 'know'. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Please first consider what 'any of Dr Jones's acquaintances…' actually means.

Does 'any' mean 'one in particular' or 'any one chosen at random' or 'all of them' or something else?

I suggest it means 'any one in particular' in which case, are you not looking at 'whether any one of Dr Jones's acquaintances knows…'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a citation for this, but my "gut feel" is that if the expected list of "any" is just one, I would treat it as singular, and if it is or could be many, I'd treat it as plural.

Like, "Jack tried to decide if any of the women he had dated was someone he would consider marrying." Presumably he's only going to marry at most one, so it's singular.

But, "Jack tried to decide if any of his college friends would make good employees for his new business." It's possible that none would, or many, or only one. But because it could be many, I'd use the plural.

I'd put your example in that second category. "Any of Dr Jones's acquaintances" could be none, one, or many. So it's plural.

Oh, in general, if something could be one or could be many, we use the plural. For example, "All the people who pass the text are qualified." It may be that only one person will pass the test, but it COULD be many, so we use plural. As opposed to, "The person who gets the highest score on the text is qualified." Now we're specifying that it can be only one.

Sometimes the wording will narrow "any" to only one. Like, "If any one here knows Dr Jones, please let me know." I use the singular "knows" because I said "any one": "one", assuming just one person. But if I said, "If any of the people here know Dr Jones ..." I'd use the plural "know", because now it could be many.

All that said, I think you could go either way and few would question it.

Answer (score 2):

Sample sentence for this context:

- An investigation is underway to discover whether any of Dr Jones's acquaintances knows/know where he is.

First, let's undo Dr Jones's acquaintances to:

- acquaintances of Dr Jones

*Reinsert* that in the sample sentence and the verb becomes clearer to see:

An investigation is underway to discover whether any of the acquaintances of Dr Jones **know** where he is. [3rd person plural]

VERSUS:

An investigation is underway to discover whether any acquaintance of Dr Jones **knows** where he is. [3rd person singular]

- Do any of your friends like cake*? [plural]

**any of** followed a plural noun is not in the third person singular. It takes a plural verb, the bare form.

*Does any friend of yours* like cake? [singular]
*Do any friends of yours like cake? [plural]

Answer (score 1):

No, we use the singular.  (Please see explanations below after "Edit").

The construction **any of + determiner + plural noun** requires a singular verb.

> An investigation is underway to discover whether **any of** Dr Jones's **acquaintances** **knows** where he is.

Edit in Response to the Comments

Our answer depends on whether we want a more formal usage or an informal one.  My answer would usually be one that gives a formal usage unless specified otherwise.

There is a [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34322/how-to-use-any-of).

> **Any of** can be followed by a verb in the singular or plural: "If **any of** your **friends** want/wants to come, they are welcome." (Plural is preferred in **everyday** language, singular is more **formal**)
> Or, as the same issue it treated in a grammar rule sheet at a New Zealand university site.[emphasis added]

> When **any of** is followed by a countable **plural** noun, the verb can be in either singular or plural form, but a singular verb is more common in a **formal** style: "If **any of** your **friends** is/are interested, let me know."[emphasis added]

Comment: "***Do any of your coworkers live*** *abroad?*" I would find the singular *Does*  to be quite odd.

Comment: **Does** any of your coworkers live abroad?

Comment: "***Does any one*** *of your coworkers live abroad*?" Please provide supporting evidence for your answer.

Comment: I disagree with using the word "requires" in this context. There is nothing ungrammatical about using 'any' as a plural. Even if singular is 'more common in a formal style' (I won't dispute this, but I haven't particularly noticed it), plural is not impossible.